# re.DOTALL isn't selecting newline character

Tags: python, regex

This is the string I am working with:
`string =`

> `'\n\n  <!----><div class="screen-reader-text" ng-if="::(ctrl.messageViewModel.isChat || ctrl.messageViewModel.isReply)" role="heading" aria-level="5">\n\n\nADMIN_COMMAND STOP\n\n, reply from YATIN </div><!---->\n\n  <!--Chat head-->\n  <div class="media-left" ng-class="{ \'hide-media-left\' : ctrl.messageViewModel.editFormVisible }">\n    <!-- Person icon -->\n    \n    <!---->\n    \n  </div>\n\n  <div class="ts-message-thread-body align-item-left" data-tid="messageThreadBody" ng-class="{\'has-attachments\': ctrl.messageViewModel.hasAttachments} ">\n    <!--EditMessage-->\n    <!---->\n    <!--EditMessage-->\n    <!----><div id="messageBody" class="message-body message-body-width" ng-if="!ctrl.messageViewModel.editFormVisible" simple-mouseenter="!ctrl.isInteropChat &amp;&amp; ctrl.messageReactionsEnabled &amp;&amp; ctrl.showMessageActions($event, this)" ng-mouseleave="!ctrl.isInteropChat &amp;&amp; ctrl.messageReactionsEnabled &amp;&amp; ctrl.hoverOutMessageBodyHandler($event)">\n      <!----><div class="message-body-top-row padded-content" ng-if="!ctrl.isHiddenByDlp" ng-class="{ \'unread-message\': ctrl.messageViewModel.isNewMessage,\n                       \'has-reactions\': ctrl.messageReactionsEnabled &amp;&amp; ctrl.messageViewModel.messageHasReaction}">\n        <div class="top-row-text-container" ng-class="{\'single-line-truncation\': ctrl.messageReactionsEnabled &amp;&amp; ctrl.messageViewModel.isRightRail}">\n          <!--Name-->\n          <div class="ts-msg-name app-small-font" data-tid="threadBodyDisplayName" dir="auto">\n`       and so on...

The main part of interest is:`>\n\n\nADMIN_COMMAND STOP\n\n, reply from`(in the ), from which I want to get `ADMIN_COMMAND STOP`

The `ADMIN_COMMAND STOP` part can be of any length and can have numbers. Also, there can be several `\n`s before and after it.

Other inputs can have:

`>\n\n\nADMIN_COMMAND REFRESH\n\n, reply from`

`>0, reply from`

`>\n\n\n\nADMIN_COMMAND STOP\n\n\n, reply from`

The output I want to get:

`ADMIN_COMMAND STOP`

`ADMIN_COMMAND REFRESH`

`0`

I came up with this:

`re.findall(">.*([A-Z 0-9]*).*, reply from",string,re.DOTALL)`

My logic:

> Check for one `>` then, zero or more of any character (including `\n`) then, find zero or more capital letter/digits and then again check for zero or more of any character (including `\n`)

Comment: Do you want to capture/match or replace the strings?

Comment: @Jan capture...

Comment: Maybe like this: [`^>\s*(\w+(?: \w+)?)\s*, reply from`](https://regex101.com/r/p7QsU5/2/) ?

Comment: @Jan I tried copying `^>\s+([A-Z]\w+ \w+)\s+` into my code but it doesn't gives output... Maybe instead of actually putting a new line the string should have `\n`...

Comment: Do you have the `multiline` mode on? Do your lines start with `>` or is there any whitespace before?

Comment: @Jan I have edited my question... please take a look at it

Comment: @Jan I haven't modified any modes... they are what they are by default...

Answer (score 1):

It *does* find a match, because it doesn't return an empty list:

```py
>>> import re
>>> string = ">\n\n\n\nADMIN_COMMAND STOP\n\n\n, reply from"
>>> re.findall(">.*([A-Z 0-9]*).*, reply from",string,re.DOTALL)
['']
```

The problem is that the capturing group `([A-Z 0-9]*)` matches zero characters, because all characters have already been consumed by the greedy `.*` before it.

You can fix it by using the negated character class `[^A-Z 0-9]` before the capture group. Now it doesn't match anything anymore, because the `_` in `ADMIN_COMMAND` is not in the character class. After fixing that, it works as expected:

```py
>>> re.findall(">[^A-Z 0-9_]*([A-Z 0-9_]*).*, reply from",string,re.DOTALL)
['ADMIN_COMMAND STOP']
```

---

Note that non-greedy matching, `.*?`, does not seem to have the desired effect in this case. Even if we put `.*?` both before and after the capture group, all characters end up being matched by the final `.*?` despite the greedy `*` in the middle:

```py
>>> re.findall(">.*?([A-Z 0-9_]*).*?, reply from",string,re.DOTALL)
['']
```

I don't quite understand why.

Comment: I had first accepted your answer because I checked it on `https://regex101.com/` but when I tried it in my code get this: `[' ']`... I think I will edit my question once more and add more of the html that I am giving as input... Please look at my question again once I have edited it...

Comment: HTML wasn't mentioned before... do you know about [parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)?

Comment: oh I didn't know that...